# newly mounted hard drive does not show up in file manager

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I am running Xubuntu 16.04 LTS (kernel version 4.4.0-51-generic) and have just added a 2nd hard drive to the system (2.0 TB SATA). I used gparted to partition and format (ext4) the drive and mounted the drive on `/mnt/sdb1` and named the partition Storage. Everything seemed fine, I was able to create a directory and copy a file to it and read it back with cat. I added the line:

`/dev/sdb1 /mnt/sdb1 ext4 defaults 0 0`

to `/etc/fstab` and rebooted. When I start up File Manager, it isn't listed in the Devices section, but if I go to `/mnt/sdb1` under File System, I see the directory I created and can view the file I added - so the drive is mounted, just not view able as a new device.

How do I get it to appear as a new device in File Manager?

Comment: In Ubuntu every thing is under `/` and I believe `/`(root) appears as `computer`. Your new hdd is there, so why do you need it to appear in the location list in file manager?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, only removable media shows up as a new device in the file manager. Anything mounted in fstab is considered a permanent mount and not considered new per se. Most file managers have the capability of creating bookmarks so you could use one of those for a shortcut to the drive you mounted at /mnt/sdb1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the bookmark to add it to the list of locations in file manager.

Steps:

1. In filemanager go to mount point: `/mnt/sdb1`
2. Change into `/mnt/sdb1` and from the filemanager menu `Bookmarks` select `Bootmark this location` from the dropdown menu.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As I know, devices mounted under `/media` directory will showing up in file managers.

So, create a directory in `/media`, for example:

```
sudo mkdir /media/my-new-drive
```

Then change your fstab from:

```
/dev/sdb1 /mnt/sdb1 ext4 defaults 0 0
```

To:

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/my-new-drive ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Reboot, or use `sudo mount -a` command to remount drives.

Should do the trick.